# Unable to redirect after capturing image

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am unable to window.locate to `nextpage.html` ever since I updated my Android version to 6.0.0. It displays a white blank screen instead of redirecting.

I was able to window.locate in Android 5.2.2, is this line of code the issue?

I read something about a Base64-encoded String that might be causing this issue.

Camera Function

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, 
        function(message) {
        window.location="nextpage.html"}, 
        {quality: 10,destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,sourceType:
        navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.Camera}
);
```

Upload Function function

```
 uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";
        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.headers = {Connection: "close"};

        var ft = new FileTransfer();

        ft.upload(imageURI, serverURL() + "/upload.php", win, fail, options);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.getPicture` accepts a success function an error function and the options object just like that `camera.getPicture(successCallback, errorCallback, options)`

In your code you only do `redirect` on the `errorCallback`, this means that redirect will not happen if the photo capture is a success.

`window.location="nextpage.html"` should go in your `uploadPhoto` function

```
uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
  // rest of yout code
  window.location="nextpage.html"
}
```